# ckeditor - onpaste event

Tags: ckeditor, paste

Does anyone know how I can attach an `onpaste` event in CKEditor 3.x?

I basically want to grab <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> data and add few text to it and then add it to the editor.

I have looked around but have not found a definitive answer. CKEditor forum is of not much help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.YourInputControlName;
editor.on('paste', function(evt) {
    // Update the text
    evt.editor.setData(evt.editor.getData() + ' your additional comments.');
}, editor.element.$);
```

Comment: Be warned that if you have IE users that use Shift+Insert to paste, your paste handler will not be executed.

Answer (score 13):

This example edits the content to be pasted by removing all img elements.

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
    ev.editor.on('paste', function (ev) {
        ev.data.html = ev.data.html.replace(/<img( [^>]*)?>/gi, '');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Your both examples are a little bit synthetic.

At first, editor.getData() gets all the content of editor, so if you want to process only pasted data, you need to get ev.data.html and paste to correct place.

```
editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
editor.on('paste', function (evt) {
    var editor = evt.editor;
    evt.stop(); // we don't let editor to paste data, only for current event
    // show loader that blocks editor changes
    $.post('clean.php', {html: evt.data.html}, function (data) {
        editor.insertHtml( data.html ); // text will be inserted at correct place
        // hide loader
    }, 'json');
});
```

Don't use functions editor.setReadonly(true/false), you won't be able to paste text in correct place (in cases with async data processing).

Comment: the attribute `evt.data.html` has become `evt.data.dataValue` in CKEditor v4+, as in another answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21677580/823020

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but thought I'd add my version of aliaksej's answer as it allows the use of a custom 'cleaner' - it didn't quite work for me until I modded it as below.

```
editor = CKEDITOR.instances[id];
editor.on('paste', function (evt) { 
   evt.stop();
   $.post('/actions/clean.php', {html: evt.data.dataValue}).done(function (data) {
      evt.editor.insertHtml(data);
   }, 'json');
});
```

Comment: the attribute `evt.data.html` has become `evt.data.dataValue` in CKEditor v4+, as in another answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21677580/823020

Answer (score 1):

```
editor = CKEDITOR.instances[id];

editor.on('paste', function (evt) {
    evt.stop();
    var data = evt.data.dataValue;

    if (window.chrome || window.safari) {
        // removing span wrapper on webkit browsers.
        data = $(data).html();
    }
    evt.editor.insertHtml(data);
});
```