# CKEditor: How to remove p elements from table cells?

Tags: ckeditor, filtering

I started using CKEditor in one of my projects and like it. One thing that I can't figure out (or find) is how to disallow one element inside another. I'd like to disallow `p` to occur within table cells `th` or `td`.

This:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p>Foo</p>        
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Should be converted to this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Foo</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

A CSS trick to hide paragraph styling is not an option.

```
table p { margin: 0; } /* I don't want this! */
```

My CKEditor is initialized like this:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'id_text', {
    allowedContent: 'table(table); table(table-striped); thead tbody tfoot tr td th;',
    toolbar: [
        ['Source'], 
        ['Format'], 
        ['Table']
    ]
});
```

It seems that the `allowedContent` property doesn't handle parent child rules. How can I filter elements when the occur inside other elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a build-in CKEditor setting to disallow tags to occur in other tags. But I did find examples on CKEditor filtering content at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010335/ckeditor-onpaste-event) and [blog](http://www.keyvan.net/2012/11/clean-up-html-on-paste-in-ckeditor/).

These articles and missing 'disallowContent' setting made me turn in an other direction: Clean on paste + server side clean.

CKEditor fires signals [on events](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.event-method-on) like [paste](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#event:paste), [insertHtml](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#event:insertHtml), [mode](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html#event:mode) change, etc. The next script adds a listener on paste. All occurrences of "Foo" will replaced with "Bar".

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
   ev.editor.on('paste', function(evt) {
   evt.data.dataValue = evt.data.dataValue.replace( /Foo/g, 'Bar' );
   }, 9);
});
```

I use CKEditor in the Django admin site and have jQuery available. Next script combines above with jQuery DOM manipulation. Each selected element will be replaced with it's own contents.

```
var $ = django.jQuery;

CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function( ev ) {
    ev.editor.on("paste", function( evt ) {
        var data = $.parseHTML(evt.data.dataValue);
        $( "th p, td p", data).each( function() {
            $( this ).replaceWith(  $( this ).contents() );
            });
        evt.data.dataValue = $('<div>').append(data).html();
        }, 9);
    });
```

Note: It is still possible to insert paragraphs in table cells via source mode or format menu. These paragraphs aren't disallowed or removed. I choose to clean data server side.